# Razor LabelFor and DropdownFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am using MVC5 with EF6. I had a requirement for creating a couple of dozen Dropdown Lists in a view that contain user-selectable preferences that are then used throughout the web application.

The problem I am having is an error on both the LabelFor and DropdownListFor lines in the razor View:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I've traced through my code to make sure `Model.Preferences` contains the data I intended, and it does. Actually, it works fine with `Html.Label` and `Html.DropdownList`, but I couldn't get the Selected Item to work that way, so I switched to `DropdownListFor` since I've found it easier to work with in that respect.

Here are snippets of my code (a work in progress):

**A simple class to hold an IEnumerable of SelectListItem:**

```
public class Preference
{
    public string ControlType;          // "Select", "Textbox"
    public string Label;                // Label of control
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListItems;
}
```

**MODEL** (An IEnumerable of Preference gives me 'Preferences')

```
public class UserPreferencesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Preference> Preferences { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
List<Preference> Preferences = new List<Preference>();

foreach (var g in uomGroups)
{
    List<SelectListItem> listitems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var w in g.Options)
    {
        ... Omitted for brevity ...

        listitems.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = w.UOMId, Value = w.UOMId, Selected = isSelected } )
    }

    var p = g.Options.ToArray();
    Preferences.Add( new Preference
    {
        ControlType = "Select",
        Label = g.Preference,
        ListItems = listitems
    });
}

model.Preferences = Preferences.AsEnumerable();

return View(model);
```

**VIEW**

```
<tbody>
@foreach (Preference preference in Model.Preferences)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(
                x => x.Label, 
                new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" }
                )
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.Label,
                new SelectList(preference.ListItems, "Value", "Text"),
                new { @class = "col-md-3 form-control" }
                )
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

From the code above, does anyone see where the problem is? I've been trying to figure this out for hours and just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
@foreach (Preference preference in Model.Preferences)
{
  ...
  @Html.LabelFor(i => preference.Label, ...
  ...
  @Html.DropDownListFor(i => preference.Label, preference.ListItems, ...
  ...
```

**EDIT**

if you need unique ID's and names, then it needs to be a `for` loop so they are correctly indexed

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Preferences.Count; i++)
{
  ...
  @Html.LabelFor(i => Model.Preferences[i].Label, ...
  ...
  @Html.DropDownListFor(i => Model.Preferences[i].Label, preference.ListItems, ..
  ...
```

this will render html like

```
<select id = "Preferences_1__Label" name="Preferences[1].Label" ...
<select id = "Preferences_2__Label" name="Preferences[2].Label" ...
```

Comment: I think I tried every possibility BUT that one. Thank you so much. I now see another problem in that I need to loop through `ListItems`, but your answer definitely fixes the problem in my question. Thank you!

Comment: The `LabelFor` is being rendered as `Label` and the ID is being rendered as `preference_label` for every control. Can you see why that might be happening? I've traced through the code and `.Label` definitely contains correct strings for each.

Comment: If you want unique ID's and names (for postback) you need a `for` loop. I'll update answer shortly

Comment: I'm looking at what you coded. I haven't ever had to deal with a situation like this before. My intent was to use the actual contents of `.Label` as the ID so that I could reference its value in the POST Controller Action and update the User's profile in the database. Maybe this is the drawback of creating all of these controls in a single object rather than referencing them individually in the Model? For example, `.Label` may contain "HeatLoad" and I actually need the text of `LabelFor` and ID of `Html.DropdownListFor` to be just that. Won't work?

Comment: The `name` attribute is used for postback, not `id`. ID's are only relevant on the client side for selecting elements.  You can always set them using `Html.DropDownFor(....., new { id="someID", name="someName" }`, but if you do this, I would question your methodology.  You have not included your post method, but if its `[HttpPost] public ActionResult(IEnumerable<Preference> model) {..` then you need to use the `for` loop as per my edit so the names are correctly indexed and the ModelBinder can bind your model.

Comment: I haven't coded the POST Action yet. Your second edit resulted in errors throughout the for {} loop. I changed the Model to an IList of Preference and that resolved the errors. Still ending up with Label as the text for each label. I'm trying to trace through the code and get a good understanding of how this effects my intended logic in the POST action.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you model was `IEnumerable<Preference>`, not `List<Preference>`. You could have used `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Preferences.Count(); i++) {..` (i.e. linq .Count() extension method - although you would probably assign the value to a variable before the loop). As for the label, the name of the property is `Label`, so `@Html.LabelFor()` should display 'Label' (or the value of any `DisplayNameAttribute`) - that's whats its for.